# How do I change the content of an element for a theme without losing the styling?

Tags: customization, themes, formatting, css

For example the theme I am using has a built in "coin calculator" that displays live prices for cryptocurrencies to fiat. It looks like this:

[image]

When I go to edit the page the code for this is just a text block with the following :

```
[currencyprice currency1="btc" currency2="usd,eur" feature="calculator"]
```

I attempted to edit it to show the price of ETH instead of bitcoin, by changing it to :

```
[currencyprice currency1="ETH" currency2="usd,eur" feature="calculator"]
```

This works functionally (it shows the correct live pricing) but I lose the styling and it looks like this:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you inspected the code and why the styling is not applied? Looks like it's just applied to a specific `btc` select. It's impossible to tell you without seeing the actual code which is rendered.

Comment: You need to examine the code and why the styling isn't being applied, like Fabian says above. Without seeing the code or site and both shortcode examples rendered on a page it's not possible for anyone to suggest anything to you.

Comment: Thanks guys. How would I go about inspecting the code? I'm very new to this. I appreciate your help.